# regular expression find all the http within [test](http://)

Tags: regex

I have tried hrs for this regex and couldn't sort it out, and seek for some help.

```
/\[.*\]\((https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})/g
```

Here is the link to my regex page [link](https://regex101.com/r/Xc5zDp/1)

https://regex101.com/r/Xc5zDp/1

I try to pick out all the links in the sentence and example like this  `[link](http://test.com)`, but it keep select both links all together

Comment: you shouldn't bother with `www`, it's just one of many possible subdomains and has no special meaning.

Comment: What exactly do you want to capture?

Comment: Make your joker in `\[.*\]` non-greedy, or use a negated character class excluding `]`.

Comment: There is only one issue here and the fix is explained in the duplicate question.

Comment: See [this regex demo where `.*` is changed with `.*?`](https://regex101.com/r/Xc5zDp/2) - the only change you need.

Comment: Thx wiktor that helps. Thx @aaron googled non greedy regard and it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your regex to this: `\[.*?\)`

Is this what you want? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a3OW3d/1)

Comment: Note that this is basic solution. You cannot use "[ ]" outside of link description but you can use "( )" wherever you want